# How to get all new committed/check-in files after last PUSH

Tags: git, github-actions, git-commit, git-push

I am trying to get last check-in files.

Requirement is user will check-in a configuration file and that config file will be passed to a script for execution. If there are 4 files checked-in then, I need to identify all 4 file and execute script in loop for each file.

I was able to do it using following steps:

```
  - name: checkout repo content
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      fetch-depth: 2

  - name: Identify and execute different Configuration files
    run: |
      echo "Check-in configuration files are"
      files=$(git diff --name-only HEAD^..HEAD)
```

However this is causing one issue.

If user perform git add, git commit, git add, git commit and then git push
It only pick file of last commit only.

I want file to be picked from last PUSH to recent PUSH.

Please suggest

Comment: Instead of `HEAD^` use `HEAD@{1}`.

Comment: Hi Jill, this didnt work. It rather give error

Comment: you say you use `github-actions`, correct ? on what events do you want to trigger your job ? one point you should address is "how do I spot the 'last state' of my branch ?"

Comment: I want job to be triggered on every push... It should check the new files which has been pushed and then run script for each pushed file

Comment: I find this link:
https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files/issues/234 

But not sure how to get file name after this... Does anyone has any idea